# Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, access-violation

I'm getting this read access violation error when I try to use one of my functions in my main.cpp file.

Here's my SpriteSheet.cpp file:

```
#include "SpriteSheet.h"
#include <wincodec.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowscodecs.lib")



SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet(const wchar_t* filename, D2DGraphics* graphics)
{
    // Init:
    this->graphics = graphics; // Save the graphics parameter for later
    bmp = NULL; //NULL our ID2D1Bitmap to start with
    HRESULT hr; // HRESULT for checking errors

    // Create a WIC factory
    IWICImagingFactory* wicFactory = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory, // CLS ID of the object we're making 
        NULL, // Not part of the aggregate
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, // DLL runs in the same process 
        IID_IWICImagingFactory, // Ref to the interface that communicates with the object. 
        (LPVOID*)&wicFactory); //The pointer that'll contain our factory. 

    // Create a decoder 
    IWICBitmapDecoder* wicDecoder = NULL;
    hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        filename, // The file name 
        NULL, // No preferred vendor 
        GENERIC_READ, // We're reading the file, not writing 
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, // Cache on load* 
        &wicDecoder); // The decoder we're making

    // Read a frame from the image:
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* wicFrame = NULL;
    hr = wicDecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicFrame);

    // Create a converter 
    IWICFormatConverter* wicConverter = NULL;
    hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicConverter);

    // Setup the converter
    hr = wicConverter->Initialize(
        wicFrame, //Frame
        GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, // Pixel Format
        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, // No dithering
        NULL, // No pallete needed
        0.0, // Alpha Transparency
        WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
    );

    // Use the converter to create a D2D1Bitmap
    graphics->GetRenderTarget()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
        wicConverter, //The Converter
        NULL, // D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES
        &bmp // Desitnation D2D1 bitmap 
    );

    if (wicFactory) wicFactory->Release();
    if (wicDecoder) wicDecoder->Release();
    if (wicConverter) wicConverter->Release();
    if (wicFrame) wicFrame->Release();
}

SpriteSheet::~SpriteSheet()
{
    if (bmp) bmp->Release();
}

// Draw the entire image at (0,0)
void SpriteSheet::Draw()
{
    graphics->GetRenderTarget()->DrawBitmap(
        bmp, // Bitmap
        D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f,
            bmp->GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height), //Destintation Rectangle
        1.0f, //Opactity 
        D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,// Interporlation is when image is stretched or shrunk. Nearest neighbor is the fastest method. 
        D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, bmp->GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height) // Source Rectangle
    );
}

void SpriteSheet::Load()
{
    //y = ySpeed = 0.0f;

    sprites = new SpriteSheet(L"circleL.png", graphics);
}

void SpriteSheet::Unload()
{
    delete sprites;
}

void SpriteSheet::Render()
{
    graphics->ClearScreen(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    sprites->Draw();
}
```

Here's my SpriteSheet.h file

```
#pragma once
#include <wincodec.h> // WIC codec header for decoding image from file
#include "D2DGraphics.h" // Includes windows and D2d1.h
#include <d2d1.h>

// Link to "windows codecs.lib", added this to the Linker->Input directory. 

class SpriteSheet
{
    D2DGraphics* graphics; // Reference to the graphics class
    ID2D1Bitmap* bmp; // Bitmap loaded file and converted to Direct2D format
    
    float y;
    float ySpeed;

    SpriteSheet* sprites;

public:
        // Constructor
        SpriteSheet(const wchar_t* filename, D2DGraphics* gfx);

        // Destructor
        ~SpriteSheet();

        // Draw the bitmap to the render target 
        void Draw();
        void Load();
        void Unload() ;
        void Render() ;
};
```

And in my main.cpp I first do:

```
SpriteSheet* sprites; // create global spritesheet object.
```

And then call this in my  `int WINAPI WinMain()`

```
sprites->Render();
```

It gives me that error when I call this, but no errors when I do not. Any ideas on what I need to change? I've read that it's probably something to do with my pointers and references for my function but I can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: _`// create global spritesheet object`_ that comment is blatantly wrong and misleading.

Comment: C++ does not create objects my magic. You have to create the `SpriteSheet` object and make your pointer point at it.

Comment: You have a `SpriteSheets` object that contains a pointer to another `SpritesSheet` object. You also have a global pointer to a `SpritesSheet` object. Both pointers are called `sprites`. I think your design is a little confused. Try think logically about what data and code really need to be part of the class and what data and code just uses the objects of the class.

Comment: _@spencer_ You might be interested in reading about [_Creational Patterns_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) for OOP.

Comment: @john I'm realizing now that I never created one, I just made a class, right? I think that's where my confusion lies.

Comment: @Spencer349 Yes a class is a *template* to create objects. But by itself it is not an object. (Just to avoid possible confusing, template is a word which has a technical meaning in C++, but here I just mean the regular English meaning.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? If the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @john That makes a lot of sense! So I create my class in my SpriteSheet.cpp, do I create my SpriteSheet object there too? Or do I do that in main?

Comment: @Spencer349 You do that wherever it is needed. But in `main` sounds like a reasonable choice. There's no essential difference between declaring an `int` variable, and declaring a `SpriteSheet` variable, `int x;` vs `SpriteSheet ss;`, both are variable declarations, both create objects. So just declare a SpriteSheet variable wherever you feel you need one in your program.

Comment: Okay, so I tried creating a `SpriteSheet` variable with the following code in `main` and ended up with the same error, without ever trying to use `render()` or `load()` Code:
`SpriteSheet ss = SpriteSheet(L"circleL.png", graphics);`

Comment: Just to clarify this was the exact error I got this time, it is different. Error: `Exception thrown: read access violation. wicFactory was nullptr.`

Comment: `D2DGraphics` Is it a user defined class? Try to provide a minimal reproducible example and edit to update the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have a chicken and egg problem. You cannot call `SpriteSheet::Load` until you have a `SpriteSheet` because it's a member function. But the only place you create a `SpriteSheet` (using a call to `new`) is inside `Load`. So there is no way you can ever invoke `Load` and no way you can invoke `Render` without first invoking `Load`.

Also:

```
SpriteSheet* sprites; // create global spritesheet object.
```

This creates a *pointer*. It does not create a `SpriteSheet` object.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, so if I create a SpriteSheet object outside of load I'll be able to call it? Would it matter if I do this in my SpriteSheet.cpp or main.cpp?